# Subclassing HashBasedTable from guava collection

Tags: java, gwt, guava

I have a multilevel map requirement and I am using Guava Table . More precisely HashBasedTable.

Since my code needs a lot of custom processing on this dataset I would like to implement a derived class e.g. EventActionRuleTable which holds a map of Event - Action objects against a source.

something like this

```
HashMap<Source , Map<Event, Action> ruleMap ;
```

I am replacing the above with a

```
Table<Source, Event , Action> ruleTable = HashBasedTable.create();
```

But to hold all my custom code I would like to subclass HashBasedTable and figured its simply not possible.

Thus I choose to go with a delegate i.e.

```
public EventActionRule extends Table<Source, Event, Action>{

private HashBasedTable<Source, Event, Action> backup = null ;

public HashBasedTable<Source, Event, Action> getBackupTable() {

    if (backupTable == null) {
        backupTable = HashBasedTable.create() ;
    }

    return backupTable;
}  

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return getBackupTable().isEmpty();
}

/**
All other methods of Table interface overridden to delegate calls to backup instance
*/
  ....
}
```

1. Is this approach correct ? Can you list issues if its not ? Any alternative approach ?
2. Is HashBasedTable Gwt serialization compatible ? I am asking since the two backup maps used internally in the HashBasedTable are annotated with @GwtTransient annotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ad 1. Your approach is correct, although you can use built-in Guava solution for using delegates - [*Forwarding Decorators*](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionHelpersExplained#Forwarding_Decorators):

> For all the various collection interfaces, Guava provides Forwarding abstract classes to simplify using the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

In your case, [`ForwardingTable`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingTable.html) is waiting for you:

```
public static class EventActionRule extends ForwardingTable<Source, Event, Action> {

    private Table<Source, Event, Action> delegate = HashBasedTable.create();

    @Override
    protected Table<Source, Event, Action> delegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

    // just an example: isEmpty (and other methods) is ready to be overriden
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        boolean isEmpty = delegate().isEmpty();
        System.out.println("Was map empty? " + isEmpty);
        return isEmpty;
    }
}
```

Ad. 2. Yes, HashBasedTable is serializable under GWT.

Comment: Just to note: you don't have to override `isEmpty()` at all with `ForwardingTable` unless you need to change its behavior. `return delegate().isEmpty()` is what it'll do by default.

Comment: @Xaerxess a question arises - what is the purpose of GwtTransient annotation applied on the internal backup maps then ?

Comment: @ColinD Of course I didn't mean to suggest overriding `isEmpty` is mandatory, I edited my answer to clarify that.

Comment: @Gautam To be honest, I don't know. Its docs in Guava says: _Private replacement for `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.GwtTransient` to work around build-system quirks. This annotation should be used only in `com.google.common.collect`._ I think it's just an implementation detail, but maybe @ColinD could answer that more accurately.

Comment: @Gautam @Xaerxess: `HashBasedTable` is marked as `@GwtCompatible(serializable = true)`, so it is GWT serializable. As to why the fields are transient for GWT, the class has a custom GWT serializer: [`HashBasedTable_CustomFieldSerializer`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava-gwt/src/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable_CustomFieldSerializer.java).